# PHP Nginx URL Rewrite confusion

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

So, I have a Nginx webserver. How would one basically replace the .php at the end with a / but still use a php file. I am creating a api and want to be able to use it like this:

```
http://example.com/api/{serverid}/{argument1}/{argument2}
```

Comment: Why not just call the php file `ìndex.php`? Then you can use it like that: `http://example.com/api?argument1=1&argument2=1&argument3=1`

Comment: I could do that, but i'm more interested in seeing how it is done by the / method. I have seen it done before.

Comment: basically, redirect ALL requests that are after `api/` into the same file( like `api.php`) for instance. Then inside of that file get the url that script is being access from (it is in one of $_SERVER variables) and explode path. This will allow you to get an array of arguments.